# Importing JSON dataset into Cassandra

Tags: json, cassandra

I have a large dataset consisting of about 80,000 records. I want to import this into Cassandra. I only see documentation for CSV format. Is this possible for JSON?

Comment: Which version cassandra that you are using.

Comment: I have version  3.7

Answer (score 4):

In 2020, you can use [DataStax Bulk Loader utility (DSBulk)](https://docs.datastax.com/en/dsbulk/doc/index.html) for loading & unloading of Cassandra/DSE data in CSV and JSON formats.  It's very flexible, and allows to load only part of data, flexibly map JSON fields into table fields, etc.  It supports Cassandra 2.1+, and very fast.

In simplest case, data loading command would look as following:

```sh
dsbulk load -k keyspace -t table -c json -url your_file.json
```

DataStax blog has a series of articles about DSBulk: [1](https://www.datastax.com/blog/2019/03/datastax-bulk-loader-introduction-and-loading), [2](https://www.datastax.com/blog/2019/04/datastax-bulk-loader-more-loading), [3](https://www.datastax.com/blog/2019/04/datastax-bulk-loader-common-settings), [4](https://www.datastax.com/blog/2019/04/datastax-bulk-loader-common-settings), [5](https://www.datastax.com/blog/2019/07/datastax-bulk-loader-counting), [6](https://www.datastax.com/blog/2019/12/datastax-bulk-loader-examples-loading-other-locations)

Comment: Thanks! Worked for me, and is indeed fast. Could you please add 'load' agrument to the example? Complains w/o it.

Answer (score 0):

To insert JSON data, add JSON to the INSERT command.
refer to this link for details
https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.3/cql/cql_using/useInsertJSON.html

Comment: I'm surprised there was no follow-up to this.  Seems to me the INSERT command is different from the COPY to load from a file -- which still as far as I can see only speaks CSV.  Can you please be more specific about how to load an entire JSON file?  basically, the inverse of sstabledump...?

Answer (score 0):

See `dsbulk` solution as the ultimate one, however you may consider this trick that converts json-formatted messages (one per line) to csv on the fly (no separate conversion necessary) and loads into Cassandra using `cqlsh`, i.e. :

`cat file.json | jq -r '[.uid,.gender,.age] | @csv' | cqlsh -e 'COPY labdata.clients(uid,gender,age) from STDIN;'`

Explanations:

This requires a `jq` utility, installed e.g. for ubuntu as `apt install jq`.

Here I have a file with the following messages:

```
{"uid": "d50192e5-c44e-4ae8-ae7a-7cfe67c8b777", "gender": "F", "age": 19}
{"uid": "d502331d-621e-4721-ada2-5d30b2c3801f", "gender": "M", "age": 32}
```

This is how I convert it to csv on the fly:

`cat file | jq -r '[.uid,.gender,.age] | @csv'`

where -r will remove some extra \", but you still end up with quoted strings:

```
"d50192e5-c44e-4ae8-ae7a-7cfe67c8b777","F",19
"d502331d-621e-4721-ada2-5d30b2c3801f","M",32
```

Now, if you create a table `clients` in keyspace `labdata` for this data using `cqlsh`:

`CREATE TABLE clients ( uid ascii PRIMARY KEY, gender ascii, age int);`

then you should be able to run the `COPY ... FROM STDIN` command above